# How to draw an image according to the pixels of another image?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, core-graphics

HI all ,what i want is to map the images.Suppose i have two images of persons,one is of fat person and another is of weak person,Now i want to match their faces ,eyes.I want to increase or decrease the face size eye size of one image according to another.As you can see in adobe photoshop you can make the face fat,make it squueze.I want to do the image manuplation in this.These types of operations i want to implement.I don't know from where to start.
Pleas guide and help me.Can i perform all this with core graphics if so then how
Any reference,tutorial address ,sample code ........appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably going to have to deal with some sort of edge detection and face recognition algorithms, at the very least, if this is to be accomplished automatically. Otherwise, if the user is going to be resizing one image to match the other, this will require simple resizing operations driven by perhaps user pinch & gestures.

UPDATE:

For manual resizing:

Download the [source code](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/687/) for the great book Cool iPhone Projects. One of the projects is called 'Touching'. This project contains code that accomplishes what you need: pinch and zoom functionality.

Comment: Its going to be autometically ,the user won't resize that,user will press a button to do that.So could you help me with that,how to do that,can you provide me some links,reference where i can get an idea to do so.If you can provide me with some links of example codes that would also be great....please guide me bro

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply ,but this is not what i am looking for, i have already done that with GEstureRecognizer,it compresses the whole image,what i want is to compress ,enlarge the face,eyes say lips as well.The face manipulation yo can say....